# how to hide the Row if there is no data fetched from backend server using axios in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I want to hide the Row if there is no data fetched from backend server using axios
below is my code.. In this code if we have data on backend then we will get this Row and if there is no data then the row still there, I want to hide this row if data is not there.

```
            <Row className="ml-0 mr-0 mt-3 articleauth">
              <Col sm={2} className="authourpic pl-1 pr-1">
                <img
                  src={item.author[0] ? item.author[0].picture : null}
                  alt=""
                />
              </Col>
              <Col sm={10} className="authorinfo pl-1 pr-1">
                <h5>{item.author[0] ? item.author[0].name : null}</h5>
                <p>
                  {item.author[0] ? item.author[0].description : null}
                </p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
```

and below the css of related class

```
.articleauth{
    border: 2px solid #eee;
}
.authourpic{
    text-align: center;
}
.authourpic img{
    height: 6.25rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px 5px;
    display: none;
}

.authourpic img[src]{
    height: 6.25rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px 5px;
    display: block;
}
.authorinfo{
    color: #747476;
}

.authorinfo p{
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use condition rendering for that

```
{ item.length > 0 && (    
<Row className="ml-0 mr-0 mt-3 articleauth">
              <Col sm={2} className="authourpic pl-1 pr-1">
                <img
                  src={item.author[0] ? item.author[0].picture : null}
                  alt=""
                />
              </Col>
              <Col sm={10} className="authorinfo pl-1 pr-1">
                <h5>{item.author[0] ? item.author[0].name : null}</h5>
                <p>
                  {item.author[0] ? item.author[0].description : null}
                </p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
) }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you can hide row

if the array is blank or you want to hide a row based on any field of object

null check for array

```
    {items && items.map((item,i)=>
      <Row className="ml-0 mr-0 mt-3 articleauth" key={i}>
              <Col sm={2} className="authourpic pl-1 pr-1">
                <img
                  src={item.author[0] ? item.author[0].picture : null}
                  alt=""
                />
              </Col>
              <Col sm={10} className="authorinfo pl-1 pr-1">
                <h5>{item.author[0] ? item.author[0].name : null}</h5>
                <p>
                  {item.author[0] ? item.author[0].description : null}
                </p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
        )}
```

based on any field of object

```
let lists = [{id:0, title: 'Hello', status: true}, 
            {id: 1, title: 'Hello 2', status: false}];

{lists && lists.map((list,i)=>
     <div key={i}>
       { list.status && <div>{list.title}</div> }
      </div>
    )}
```